# Instantiated gameObject's self-written component is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement chest mechanic in my game. When a user touches to chest, chest disappears and heart shows up. When player touches the instantiated heart, it must disappear and add 1 to life value, but the script is not working.

Chest.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject heart;
    public GameObject _heart; //Instantiated heart.
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            Vector3 insPos = transform.position;
            _heart = Instantiate(heart,new Vector3(insPos.x,insPos.y+0.5f,insPos.z),Quaternion.identity);
            _heart.AddComponent<Heart>();
            _heart.GetComponent<Heart>().ls = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<LifeSystem>();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Heart.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Heart : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LifeSystem ls;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            SoundManager.PlaySound("CollectCoinSound");
            ls.lifes += 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I check the components of the instantiated heart when player touches the chest and I can see that life system reference is added and so heart script is.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [general collision rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74854371/7111561) I would make sure your fields have the correct type in the first place and already attach the `Heart` component to your prefab.

Also there is no need for find .. You already know the reference to the player you are colliding with

```
public class Chest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Heart heartPrefab;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("Player"))
       {
            Instantiate(heart, transform.position + Vector3.up * 0.5f), Quaternion.identity);

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and then simply do

```
public class Heart : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.TryGetComponent<LifeSystem>(out var ls))
        {
            SoundManager.PlaySound("CollectCoinSound");
            ls.lifes += 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and rather have the `LifeSystem` attached to your player object.

In general I would kind of expect both eventually triggered at the same time since the heart might be already triggered if spawning right where the player is

Comment: It's still not working... Heart is being spawned but doesn't do the rest...

Comment: I can't say much about your project without having it... I suppose there are colliders (2D) on your heart prefab? A Rigidbody2D involved.. No strange layers and layer settings?

Comment: Yeah, heart prefab has 2d box collider which has "Is Trigger" on. Heart doesn't have rigidbody though, the player has. And no strange layers or layer settings... Thanks a lot for atleast trying, appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to meet these conditions in order for `OnTriggerEnter2D` to be called on the spawned `Hearth`:

1. At least one between `Player` and `Hearth` need to have a `Rigidbody2D` component
2. Both `Player` and `Hearth` need to have a collider with `IsTrigger = true`
3. `Player` and `Hearth` GameObjects need to be on two interacting layers in the [collision matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)
4. The `Hearth` component needs to be either on the same GameObject with a collider or on the same GameObject with the `RigidBody2D`

I actually simplified rules 1 and 2 a bit to show the most common use-case: if you want to know the actual rules for collisions, you can find them [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) (see the matrix at the bottom).